# error when trying to display 1 as YES from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a column in a database called ActDefect that displays null or 1. 
In my GridView I want it to display YES instead of 1, and NO if its null.
But I am getting this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>       Parameter name: index

Here is the code for ActDefect:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ActDefect" HeaderText="Defects" SortExpression="ActDefect"></asp:BoundField>

int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("ActDefect");
if (main.ActDefect != null)
{
      e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "YES";
}
else
{
      e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "NO";
}
```

it says the error is with the line `e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "YES";`

Comment: what is the value of `index` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing this

```
int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("ActDefect");
```

to this

```
int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Defects");
```

also, if that doesn't work, instead of:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ActDefect" HeaderText="Defects" SortExpression="ActDefect"></asp:BoundField>
```

write this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Defects">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ActDefect").ToString())  ? "No" : "Yes" %>' runat="server"  id="myID"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and you can delete your C# code

Answer (score 0):

Have you debbuged and checked the value of "index" before it reaches the IF statement? it might be a problem of determining the column with the header ActDefect in your gridview

Comment: the value of index is 0